# How to start develop and integrate AR with Cloud/DB?

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, cloud, augmented-reality, iot

How to start develop Augmented Reality application that can integrate AR with cloud/database using Unity. I want to create an application which can recognize multiple marker and match it with cloud/database stored models. The models can extract from cloud to display in the application.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this yet? The guy shows all kinds of things
 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClm2DY6pj3ygKoKhEVr7KFw